# Why no Kafka data ingestion for some batches?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm using Spark Streaming with Kafka with the batch interval being 10 seconds. I'm sure that the Kafka queue always has data to provide for Spark in time. But at times Spark might be stacked over there for couple minutes and outputted the following log continually:

```
INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453521260000 ms
INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453521280000 ms
INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453521300000 ms
INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453521320000 ms
```

Any ideas please, why Spark would be stacked there and kept adding jobs, but no any progress?

Comment: How do you observe progress?  Do you have logs indicating when messages have been consumed from Kafka?

Comment: I'm using Spark master and slave logs. Yes, I could see Spark was very slowly consuming Kafka messages.

Comment: Could you add a minimal version of the job code to your question?

Comment: Could you please also share screenshot of Streaming tab in Spark  UI? It could be that jobs are just being queued

Comment: Looking at the "Added jobs" messages I can surely say that either the batch interval is *not* 10 secs or they're incomplete because the difference between times is 20k ms, i.e. 20 secs. Can you please post the entire message log for a single job generation? What Kafka dstream are you using - direct, with a receiver or something else?